# Get-WmiObject to combine to outputs

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I was executing below script to obtain the server patch version of Skype for business servers.

I need the output as server patch name, version and computername.

```
$x = Get-Content "E:\temp\servers.txt" 
foreach ($y in $x) 
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $y -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject -query ‘select name, version from win32_product’ | where {$_.name -like “*Skype for Business server 2015, core*”}} | Select-object name, Version, @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$y}} | ft -AutoSize
}
```

But I am receiving output as below

```
Name                                            Version      ComputerName   
----                                            -------      ------------   
Skype for Business Server 2015, Core Components 6.0.9319.598 D221412xxxxxx

Name                                            Version      ComputerName   
----                                            -------      ------------   
Skype for Business Server 2015, Core Components 6.0.9319.598 D221412xxxxxxxx

Name                                            Version      ComputerName   
----                                            -------      ------------   
Skype for Business Server 2015, Core Components 6.0.9319.598 D221412xxxxxx



Name                                            Version      ComputerName   
----                                            -------      ------------   
Skype for Business Server 2015, Core Components 6.0.9319.598 D221412xxxxxxx


Name                                            Version      ComputerName   
----                                            -------      ------------   
Skype for Business Server 2015, Core Components 6.0.9319.598 D221412xxxxxx
```

I don't need my header tiles in every line of output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, you dont have to invoke the command. `Get-WmiObject` has its own `-ComputerName` Parameter. Also, what you need to do is expand the property. Just gonna be a little trickier to output

Comment: @Abraham could you please re-write the script line for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are getting headers for each computer because the select
  statement is inside the foreach loop.
- Invoke-command accepts multiple
  computers so you dont need a foreach loop.
- use server-side filtering
  where possible.

  ```
  $x = Get-Content "E:\temp\servers.txt" 
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $x -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject -query "select name, version from win32_product where name like 'Skype for Business server 2015, Core%'"} | 
   Select-object PSComputerName,name, Version
  ```

**For future:**

- Use Get-CimInstance because Get-wmiobject is deprecated.
- Do not use win32_product because it can potentially lead to msi corruption. Use
  the registry instead.

https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/find-installed-software